# Centroid of circle intersection

Tags: integration, geometry, centroid

[image]

> A region $R$ is bounded by the circle radius $4$ centred at $(5,0)$, the circle radius $2$ centred at $(0,0)$ and the x-axis, as shown.
>
> What is the centroid of this region?

Finding the top point of $R:=(x_p, y_p)$:

$$\begin{align} 
2^2 &=x_p^2 + y_p^2\\
4^2 &= (5-x_p)^2+y_p^2\\
16 &=25 -10x_p+x_p^2+y_p^2\\
&=29-10x_p\\
x_p &= {\small\frac{13}{10}} = 1.3\\
\color{gray}{y_p} &= \color{gray}{\sqrt{4-1.3^2} = \sqrt{2.31}}
\end{align}$$

Now I could integrate across the left and right areas either side of $x=1.3$, find the two centroids and  make an interpolation weighted by the areas either side, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you integrate along the $y$ axis? It looks easier to me than doing the calculations in two steps... But besides that, I don't see a more geometric approach (yet)